# Unable to implement code for scanning songs using Mediastore

Tags: android, android-cursor, mediastore

I'm trying to implement this code into my Music Player that I made using [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-building-audio-player-tutorial/) tutorial. I need to implement this code to scan all music files in SD card using "MediaStore".

```
public class SongsManager {
// SDCard Path
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getPlayList(){
Cursor cursor = resolver.query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, new String [] {"ARTIST", "DURATION", "TITLE", "_DATA", "ALBUM"}, null, null, null);
    while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
    HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
    song.put("artist", cursor.getString(0));
    song.put("duration", cursor.getString(1));
    song.put("songTitle", cursor.getString(2));
    song.put("songPath",cursor.getString(3));
    song.put("album",cursor.getString(4));
    // Adding each song to SongList
    songsList.add(song);
    }
    return songsList;
    }}
```

Basically I'm unable to solve a couple errors on this line:

```
Cursor cursor = resolver.query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, new String [] {"ARTIST", "DURATION", "TITLE", "_DATA", "ALBUM"}, null, null, null);
```

The errors are:

> Multiple markers at this line
>     - resolver cannot be resolved
>     - Cursor cannot be resolved to a type

There is no Quickfix for "Cursor cannot be resolved to a type" part but for the resolver part the Quickfixes include

- Create local variable 'resolver'
- Create field 'resolver'
- Create parameter 'resolver'
- Create class 'resolver'
- Create constant 'resolver'
- and few useless change to(s)..

I searched and tried almost every other solution available on the web that is related to my problem but it didn't work for me. So I have to ask this question here. And I admit that I'm not really good at this so I request that please answer in a way that a noob like me doesn't have issue implementing the code from your answer.

Answer (score 0):

`resolver` presumably is supposed to be a `ContentResolver`. Typically, you get one of those by calling `getContentResolver()` on some `Context`, like your `Activity`.

Comment: Didn't really get it but anyways I found some different pseudocode which works for me.